# Setting user nickname and displayname to shortened email

Tags: php, functions

I am trying to set the user's display_name and nickname to the first part of the email address of a user (before the @) upon login if nickname is not set.

So far I've got:

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'force_nicknames_on_login' );

function force_nicknames_on_login( $username ) {
    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );

    $nickname = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'nickname', true );
    $email = $user_info->user_email;

    $email = substr( $email, 0, strpos( $email, "@" ) );

    if ( empty ($nickname) ) {
        $nickname = $email;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $nickname ) && ( $user->data->display_name != $nickname ) ) {
        $userdata = array(
            'ID' => $user->ID,
            'nickname' => $nickname,
            'display_name' => $nickname,
        );

        wp_update_user( $userdata );
    }
}
```

Which seems to set the display name up as the nickname if it's already set, but if the user registers without a nickname, it doesn't pull through the email before @.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to rethink your logic that decides to set the empty nickname to the email.

You need to do this, in this order:

- if the nickname is empty, set it to the email (and strip out the part after the '@' if you want.
- then you should have values for display name (whatever they entered), and nickname (whatever they entered, or their email if no entry)
- and then you can store the values

I note that there might be problems with the resultant data, though. The email address might not have a good 'visible' (recognizable?) value for the nickname. There might be some values of emails that wouldn't look good as a nickname.

So perhaps requiring a nickname might be better, or letting the nickname be blank. Perhaps asking for 'first/last name', email, and nickname (visible name). If the visible name is empty, then put in the first/last name. But alert the user that their first/last name will be used, so they may want to enter a nickname. (And then there is the GDPR stuff...)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I set the nickname to be required when registering, so this should not be an issue anymore. This was originally an issue because it was setting First+Last name as the default display name, which I wasn't comfortable with.